# How do I shift a letter of the alphabet in C++?

Tags: c++

Say I wanted to shift the letter 'A' into the letter 'D'. I can't seem to find anything that shows how to do that in C++ 17. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "shift"? You could just do `chr += 3;`

Comment: `'A'+3` is how. That is if it's of char type.

Comment: you will have to work out what to do with 'z'.

Comment: Provide code, please. What are you doing?

Answer (score 1):

Try just adding 3 to the character:

```
char myChar = 'A';
char shifted = myChar + 3;    // shifted is now 'D'
```

Comment: Note that this relies on the character encoding having contiguous representations for letters. That assumption is not guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Is there any way to do the same thing to a string?

Comment: You can iterate over each character and do that.  Keep in mind that you'll need to handle the case where the shift goes past 'Z'.

Answer (score 1):

Just treat each character like an integer and shift ‘A’ according to its ASCII value. This works because in c++ characters are encoded as 7-bit integers.

http://www.asciitable.com

Looking at the table we see that ‘A’ = 65 and ‘D’ = 68. So to shift ‘A’ to ‘D’, simply add 3 to ‘A’ like so:

```
char a = 'A';
a += 3;

std::cout << a;
```

Output:

```
D
```

Comment: This works because when your compiler uses ASCII, characters are encoded as 7-bit ASCII values. There are other character encodings than ASCII, and for some of them, this won't work. You won't run into them if you stick to PC, Macs, etc. Just be aware of that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
char letter_A='A';
char letter_D=letter_A+3;
```